# ie8 chrashes in xp, html5shim issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, html5shiv, contao

the site http://www.taa.de always crashes in IE8 on windows XP when loading a new page. I removed one javascript after another and found that the error was gone when removing html5shim.js.

There is no problem in IE7 (XP+windows7) an IE8 on windows 7.

The site was build in contao 2.11.5 and uses jquery 1.6.2 and typekit.

Thanks for helping

edit: when switching off jQuery it works. Are there any known interferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the latest jQuery version. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was having XP/IE8 crashing issues as well; I narrowed it down to the TypeKit loader, which I will now just shut off for IE8.